# Visualforce page in Mobile card in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

i am using salesforce 1.In account page layout i added a page in mobile card section.but its showing some part of page and cropped other part of page.is there a way to assign full page to that visualforce page instead of clicking of that small page segment and then it will redirect to visualforce page.right now its bottom part contain related lists. Or this is the only option ??

Answer (score 4):

Mobile cards are not build for showing complete Visualforce page at once. Think about the scenario where a Visualforce page has 1000 records to show and you want it in mobile card. It will not be the best practice for mobile view.

Mobile cards are built to show summarised information not the complete detail. To see complete detail user has to click on that to view complete detail. From the mobile user experience, too much information or detailed information is not a good practice.

So the best way to use mobile card is design Visualforce like it should first show some important information in summarised way and then user may click to view complete report on that information.

Comment: How can you tell if the view is as a mobile card and summarized or if it is the full view?